# is there any difference between where clause and using association object for performance

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, query-optimization

for example we have association between products and order.
Will there be any difference between these two queries that are written below .
Are thy both same in execution time and performance wise

```
@products = @order.products
```

```
@products = Product.where(order_id: @order.id)
```

or can we improve this above query in any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do the same thing. If you run the query in the console, you will see something like this

```
Order Load (0.3ms) SELECT "orders".* from "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2, [["ID", 1], "LIMIT", 1]
Product Load (0.3ms) SELECT "products".* from "products" WHERE "products"."order_id" = $1 [["ORDER_ID", 1]]
```

Comment: i know they both do the same thing but which one is good for execution time and performance wise ?

Comment: They're both the same. In both it needs to find the order then select the product for that order. The performance tweaks would depend on what you want to do with that. Are you going to access any of the order information for each product? If so then you'll want to eager load the order, @order.products.include(:order) or Product.include(:order).where(order_id: @order.id)

Comment: Convention would dictate the first option.

Comment: Doesn't  @order.products gets data from cache after first execution ,
and in case of where it gets data every time from database ?

Comment: PRetty much all queries use the cache after first execution

Answer (score 1):

They both do the same thing and the performance is the same. These queries will use the order id to get the products from the product table. The related sql query will be the same.

The only difference is that if you have used eager loading before loading the order then this query will run in memory as the related products would already be loaded:
@products = @order.products